# Call function from string name

Tags: vimscript, functions

I am trying to achieve the following :

1. Having a set of predefined functions in my script
2. Having a map of relation between the functions and their argument
3. Calling the functions with their argument dynamically

Here is the code that I have :

```
function! s:A(a) abort
  return 'A'.a:a
endfunction

function! s:B(b) abort
  return 'B'.a:b
endfunction

let s:functions_map ={
      \ 'A': 'aa',
      \ 'B': 'bb'
      \ }

function! s:CallMap() abort
  for [l:key, l:value] in items(s:functions_map)
    let l:Current_function = function(l:key)
    echo l:Current_function(l:value)
  endfor
endfunction

command! Call call <SID>CallMap()
```

When I run `Call` I get the following message :

```
E700: Unknown function: A
```

Do you know where the issue could be coming from ?

**Edit** : 
I replace `l:current_function` by `l:Current_function` to solve another error that was not directly related to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined the function `s:A`, but tried to call `function('A')` - they are not the same: function `A()` doesn't exist. (`:h E700` points directly to the `function()` call)

You'll probably have to use `'<SID>A'` in place of `'A'` as key (same for B, of course).

Also, `:h call()` (with braces; not `call`) might help with the handling of the function arguments.

Comment: Right ! I replace my function creation with `function('<SID>'.l:key)` and it worked :) +1 for the `call()` it will replace my function creation.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another simple example to elaborate the previous solutions.

```
" -------------------------------------
" These are representative functions
function! Test0()
  echom "This is Test0"
endfunction

function! Test1()
  echom "This is Test1"
endfunction

function! Test2()
  echom "This is Test2"
endfunction
" -------------------------------------
function! Test(func_name_str)
  echom "This is Test"
  " Note: function reference name should start with Captical letter
  " Create function reference
  let FuncRef = function(a:func_name_str)
  " Call the function using its reference
  call FuncRef()
endfunction
" -------------------------------------
```

Source above code. And use it as below,

```
:call Test('Test0')
:call Test('Test1')
```